# Elasticsearch javascript file could not load

Tags: javascript, file, elasticsearch

I have written a javascript function that calculates the closest distance between one point with multiple locations and put it into /etc/elasticsearch/scripts/my_file.javascript and using `script mode` to perform this function in `elasticsearch`, but unfortunately, I get an error.

> u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'script_score: the script could not be loaded'

Anyone can help me! Thanks in advance

Here is code in my script file

```
(function(){
var i, locations, arcDist, closest, distance;
arcDist = function( lat1, lat2, lon1, lon2 ){
    var R = 6371 // earth radius
      , CI = 0.017453292519943295 // pi/180
      , dLat = (lat2-lat1) * CI / 2
      , dLon = (lon2-lon1) * CI / 2
      , sinDLat = Math.sin(dLat)
      , sinDLon = Math.sin(dLon)
      , a = sinDLat*sinDLat + sinDLon*sinDLon * Math.cos(lat1*CI)*Math.cos(lat2*CI)
      , c = 2*Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    return R * c;
}
locations = doc["locations"].getValues();
closest = arcDist( lat, locations[0].lat(), lon, locations[0].lon() );
for( i=1; i < locations.length; i++ ) {
    distance = arcDist( lat, locations[i].lat(), lon, locations[i].lon() );
    if(distance < closest) {
      closest = distance;
    }
}
return closest;
```

})();

and here is a part of whole code I use to call my script file

```
search_term["query"]["function_score"] = {
            "query": {
                "bool": bool_filter,
            },
            "script_score": {
                "script": {
                    "file": "my_file",
                    "lang": "javascript"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that functionality of ElasticSearch, but do you think this is a problem it detects in the script, or could it be a syntax error with the way the ElasticSearch load function is called?  Can you post your javascript function and the call to the ElasticSearch function to help add context to the question for others?

Comment: Personally, I think this problem is due to I put my script file into wrong place